# Could not synchronize database state with session Exception in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a table bean as :

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "employee_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private long id;
}
```

and when i try to insert row in database an Exception appear "Could not synchronize database state with session":

```
19658 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
119658 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Batch entry 0 insert into employee (basic_salary, code, fk_department_id, email, first_name, ip_phone_extension, is_default, last_name, password, threshold, voice_model, voice_validate, employee_id) values (NULL, 222, NULL, admi222222222n@xeno-solutions.com, sdfasfd, 21312, 0, fdsafsad, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, 10) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
119658 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
119658 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "employee_pkey"
  Detail: Key (employee_id)=(10) already exists.
119658 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy35.addEmployee(Unknown Source)
    at com.xeno.phoneSuite.beans.EmployeeBean.addOrUpdateEmployee(EmployeeBean.java:256)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
```

why this exception appear and how i can solve it ?
note: I use sql Script to add data to data base

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log writes:

> 119658 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "employee_pkey"
>     Detail: Key (employee_id)=(10) already exists.

IDs must be unique, but you attempted to create a new Employee with an ID that already exists in the database. It is the job of the id generator to ensure such a thing doesn't happen.

The hibernate documentation [writes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator):

> SEQUENCE (called seqhilo in Hibernate): uses a hi/lo algorithm to efficiently generate identifiers of type long, short or int, given a named database sequence.

The most common reason why that generator fails is if its sequence is out of sync with with entity tables, for instance because entities were created without going through hibernate (for instance by an SQL script), and the sequence not updated.

Comment: That depends on which database you use. Check its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the line:

```
Detail: Key (employee_id)=(10) already exists
```

gives it away. Check your database for something with:

```
select * from employee where employee_id=10
```

Comment: I creat sql script to insert into database and id 10  exists

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by  GenerationType.IDENTITY

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employee_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private long id;
}
```

that will make for each table sequence and in sql script we not add id in insert statement